# nsurlstoraged and CPU usage

Tags: cpu, macos

Since yesterday `nsurlstoraged` is constantly using a huge amount of CPU. Nothing shows up in the logs but `opensnoop` shows that the process is accessing

```
/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mail/fsCachedData
```

The directory contains XML files from the beginning of the month (from October 1. at 8:12) up to now (growing). I now have more than 9 GB of cached data and a new file is created every 2-3 seconds.

After a reboot the `nsurlstoraged` starts again with the same behaviour.

Any idea on how to stop it or on when it will stop by itself?

Comment: I've been having the same problem since the early Yosemite betas. So far the only thing I've found to help is keeping an eye on it and using Force Quit in Activity Monitor when it gets out of hand.

Comment: Add me to the list of people having the issue as well, although *I* don't even have a /Library/Containers directory.  What I can tell you is that this is happening on a 1 week old rMBP that shipped with Mavericks and was upgraded to Yosemite release.

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6683089) solved the issue for me:

- Make sure you have a recent backup
- Quit Safari (if it is running)
- In Finder, type <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> and enter `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari`
- A Finder window will open, with the `com.apple.Safari` folder selected
- Delete the whole folder
- Restart Safari

Comment: But that help you per hour or is permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I [restarted my computer in Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262), and that fixed the issue for me for about a week.  Among other things, Safe Mode rebuilds certain caches, including (at least some of) those in the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari` folder noted in [@coolbreeze's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150945/nsurlstoraged-and-cpu-usage/158722#158722), so I expect this will do the same thing that does.

I didn't have to actually log in while in Safe Mode, mind you.  I restarted the machine in Safe Mode, then when I saw the login screen I restarted normally and the caches had been cleared.

It may be wise to simply shut down your computer every week or so between uses.

All that said, I'd love to hear if anyone has a more permanent solution.

---

- macOS High Sierra (10.13.2)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)
- 3.5 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon E5
- 64 GB 1866 MHz DDR3

Answer (score 0):

I purchase IMAC -2020,
I tried removing the wired LAN to understand the wifi connection.

then CPU's accountsd goes up 455% and pan cooler fast and disk's nsurlsotraged high.

so I TURN OFF WIFI, connect Wired LAN again.

As you might expect, the cpu and disk are back to normal, and the fan cooler is quiet. This method may vary from person to person, but please try it.